# calculate height of UILabel

Tags: swift, xcode

I've got 2 uiLabels and each round the text inside of them changes and so are the number of lines and height is the uilabel box. 
I've tried to get the height using `uiLabel.frame.height` . But it seems like it only calculates the height of the box as if there's only just one line inside (the height is always the same even tho it's clearly different when there are 4 lines or just 2 lines.)

What am I missing?

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: there's no code to show I've tried to get the height using a frame. height but it always returns the height as if there's only just 1 line.  I need to get the actual in order to align another property

Answer (score 0):

In the UILABEL settings set lines = 0 and in the autolayout, do not create any constant related to height. The label will adjust according to the size of your text.

The size is always returning as the size of a line because in the UILABEL settings the lines attribute is 1.

Comment: But how can i get the height of the UILabel ? I need its height to align another property

Comment: Change the UILABEL settings to lines = 0 it will bring the correct height

Comment: I've changed the line height to 0 I keep getting the same height when i print the result of uilabel.frame.height

Comment: when you set lines zero? this will only work if you set 0 for the number of lines in the inspector attribute.
You cannot also have height constants for the label, otherwise it will have a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you ask for height (with `uiLabel.frame.height`) too early, when the view isn't properly laid out.

In which function do you ask for height? In UIViewController you should use `func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` instead of functions like `viewDidLoad()`. In subviews you can get correct height in `func layoutSubviews()`.

And also, you can also try and call sizeToFit() on your label after it gets the text. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622630-sizetofit)

Comment: but i need to use the height of the UIlabel in order to find where to locate another item, basically, i have 2 labels then there's space then there's keyboard. I want to get the size between the keyboard the labels so i need to get the height of the labels for that

Comment: Where do you call this? In which function you are trying to get the height of label and move other items?

Comment: ive tried to call it in viewDidLoad and viewDidLayoutSubviews. 
I keep getting 118.666 as the frame height even tho it's clearly incorrect as each time the height is different as there's a different amount of text